# Matlab general matrix indexing for accesing several rows

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Edit for clarity:

I have two matrices, p.valor 2x1000 and p.clase 1x1000. p.valor consists of random numbers spanning from -6 to 6. p.clase contains, in order, 200 1:s, 200 2:s and 600 3:s. What I wan´t to do is

> Print p.valor using a diferent color/prompt for each clase determined in p.clase, as in following [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnJHk.jpg).

I first wrote this, in order to find out which locations in p.valor represented where the 1,2 respective 3 where in p.clase

```
 %identify the locations of all 1,2 respective 3 in p.clase
    f1=find(p.clase==1);
    f2=find(p.clase==2);
    f3=find(p.clase==3);

%define vectors in p.valor representing the locations of 1,2,3 in p.clase     
     x1=p.valor(f1);
     x2=p.valor(f2);
     x3=p.valor(f3);
```

There is 200 ones (1) in p.valor, thus, is x1=(1:200). The problem is that each number one(1) (and, respectively 2 and 3) represents TWO elements in p.valor, since p.valor has 2 rows. So even though p.clase and thus x1 now only have one row, I need to include the elements in the same colums as all locations in f1.

So the different alternatives I have tried have not yet been succesfull. Examples:

```
plot(x1(:,1), x1(:,2),'ro')
hold on
plot(x2(:,1),x2(:,2),'k.')
hold on
plot(x3(:,1),x3(:,2),'b+')
```

and

```
    y1=p.valor(201:400);
    y2=p.valor(601:800);
    y3=p.valor(1401:2000);

     scatter(x1,y1,'k+')
     hold on
     scatter(x2,y1,'b.')
     hold on
     scatter(x3,y1,'ro')
```

and

```
y1=p.valor(201:400);
y2=p.valor(601:800);
y3=p.valor(1401:2000);


plot(x1,y1,'k+')
hold on
plot(x2,y2,'b.')
hold on
plot(x3,y3,'ro')
```

My figures have the axisies right, but the plotted values does not match the correct figure provided (see top of the question).

Ergo, my question is: how do I include tha values on the second row in p.valor in my plotted figure?

I hope this is clearer!

Answer (score 1):

Values from both rows simultaneously can be accessed using this syntax:

```
X=p.value(:,findX)
```

In this case, resulting X matrix will be a matrix having 2 rows and `length(findX)` columns.

Comment: I added my code to the question so you can see how I tried to apply what you said. However, when I do this I get a figure with all the correct y-values, but only 1 and 2 for x-values. My figure is supposed to look something like [this](http://imgur.com/NDfHWM4)

Comment: @MatlabNoob if you have the stats toolbox you should check out the gscatter function

Answer (score 1):

```
M = magic(5)

M =

   17   24    1    8   15
   23    5    7   14   16
    4    6   13   20   22
   10   12   19   21    3
   11   18   25    2    9

M2 = M(1:2, :)

M2 =

   17   24    1    8   15
   23    5    7   14   16
```

Matlab uses **column major indexing**. So to get to the next row, you actually just have to add 1. Adding 2 to an index on M2 here gets you to the next column, or adding 5 to an index on M

e.g. `M2(3)` is `24`. To get to the next row you just add one i.e. `M2(4)` returns `5`.To get to the next column add the number of rows so `M2(2 + 2)` gets you `1`. If you add the number of columns like you suggested you just get gibberish.

So your method is very wrong. Freude's method is 100% correct, it's much easier to use subscript indexing than linear indexing for this. But I just wanted to explain why what you were trying doesn't work in Matlab. (aside from the fact that `X=p.value(findX findX+1000)` gives you a syntax error, I assume you meant `X=p.value([findX findX+1000])`)

Comment: Thank you! I tried to do use column major indexing as well, by writing  `x1=p.valor(f1);`
`y1=p.valor(f1+1);`                                  `plot(x1,y1,'r.')`   but the plot I get now have an x-axis spanning from 0 to 600 )i.e the number of columns), when my values only span from -6 to 6. What can I do so that it´s clear it´s the values of the numbers in the specific locations and not the location itself I want to plot?

Comment: @MatlabNoob, sorry I'm not following you.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I don`t follow myself @Dan. I will update my question so that it is more easy to understand

Comment: @MatlabNoob OK I think this is what you want: `plot(x1(:,1), x1(:,2),'r.')`

Comment: Hmm, got me a figure with only three symbols. I have edited now for more clarity. Thank you again @Dan